# Error: No value for "ColumnName". Get JSON value in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I want to get f_index value from JSON into my Android App. I am getting an error "No value for f_index.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for f_index
```

If I remove the below line then I am able to get the lat, long and is_local values properly and further use them.

```
ill_id_data.add(ill_jo.getInt("f_index"));
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong here?

JSON received in the app which I pass to parse method.

```
{
"server_response": [{
    "f_index": "3",
    "lat": "21.9159",
    "long": "78.1021",
    "is_local": "0"
}, {
    "f_index": "6",
    "lat": "25.0751",
    "long": "54.9476",
    "is_local": "0"
}, {
    "f_index": "7",
    "lat": "14.6773",
    "long": "75.542",
    "is_local": "1"
}, {
    "f_index": "8",
    "lat": "21.9159",
    "long": "78.1021",
    "is_local": "0"
}, {
    "f_index": "9",
    "lat": "25.8079",
    "long": "86.0449",
    "is_local": "1"
}]
}
```

Code for parsing the JSON in my App.

```
ArrayList<Double> ill_lat_data = new ArrayList<Double>(3);
ArrayList<Double> ill_long_data = new ArrayList<Double>(3);
ArrayList<Interger> ill_id_data = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
ArrayList<Integer> ill_is_local_data = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);

public void parseIndexLatLngJSON() {

    int count_ill = 0;

    try {
        ill_json_object = new JSONObject(json_index_latlng);
        ill_json_array = gm_json_object.getJSONArray("server_response");

        while (count_ill < ill_json_array.length()) {
            JSONObject ill_jo = ill_json_array.getJSONObject(count_ill);

            ill_id_data.add(ill_jo.getInt("f_index"));
            Log.d("tag_last_check", String.valueOf(ill_jo.getInt("f_index")));
            ill_lat_data.add(ill_jo.getDouble("lat"));
            ill_is_local_data.add(ill_jo.getInt("is_local"));
            ill_long_data.add(ill_jo.getDouble("long"));

            count_ill++;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my php file.

```
$sql="SELECT id,lat,`long` FROM newsphere_one WHERE lat != 0 OR `long` != 0;";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$hostname,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($response, array("f_index" => $row[0],"lat" => $row[1],"long" => $row[2],"is_local" => $row[3]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully observe the below two lines once again

```
ill_json_object = new JSONObject(json_index_latlng);
ill_json_array = gm_json_object.getJSONArray("server_response");
```

In line 1, you had assigned the json_index_latlng to the object **ill_json_object**

But In line 2, you are accessing your server response from  **gm_json_object**.

Check your code once again,
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
ill_id_data.add(ill_jo.getInt("f_index"));
```

tries to get a integer, while in your json it's defined as a string.
Try and get the string then cast it to int. Try to use:

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

Comment: I tried this - ill_id_data.add(Integer.valueOf(ill_jo.getString("f_index"))); 
But still same error. If what you are saying is the case how am i getting 'is_local'.

Comment: Most probably you have an error in your json structure. Try using optString("f_index"). It will return an empty string if no "f_index" is found. If that's the case, using optString should not result in errors

Comment: Yes, I had tried optString & OptInt too. It does not result in an error but the log prints 0 which means I didn't get the value. On printing the JSON string I clearly see that there is a value.

Comment: That's weird.. can you post an entire log? The "server_response" array.

Comment: The JSON that I have posted with the question is exactly the response in the app.

Answer (score 0):

In php

change the below line from

```
array_push($response, array("f_index" => $row[0],"lat" => $row[1],"long" => $row[2],"is_local" => $row[3]));
```

to

```
array_push($response, array("f_index" => intval($row[0]),"lat" => $row[1],"long" => $row[2],"is_local" => $row[3]));
```

use `intval($row[0])` to convert to integer

or

use `floatval($row[0])` to convert to float

Comment: I converted it to intval but it didn't work. I am getting the JSON without " " i.e like this {"server_response": [{"f_index": 3,"lat": "21.9159",.... Later while getting the value got the same error.